# Reference on semigroup theory and parabolic PDEs

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, semigroups-of-operators

Recently started to study semigroup theory. My background is equivalent to the first three chapters of the Jack Hale's book *"Asymptotic behavior of dissipative systems"*.

Looking for a reference to an article in the topic. It may be a review, but contains interesting results for a beginner, and also with some possible research topics.

Juan Valdez

Comment: Do you know Pazy?

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned by Timur, one classic reference is [Pazy](http://books.google.hu/books?id=sIAyOgM4R3kC&dq=pazy+semigroups&hl=de&source=gbs_navlinks_s), where you can read of the classic results (till around 1980).

An excellent book is [Engel and Nagel](http://www.fa.uni-tuebingen.de/research/publications/1999/one-parameter-semigroups-for-linear-evolution-equations/engel-nagel_one-parameter-semigroups.pdf), which contains lots of applications and recent results.

If you are interested in particular in parabolic problems, then [Lunardi](http://books.google.hu/books?id=mWojiHzg9bEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Lunardi&hl=de&ei=x7p7TtuNGdGQswaSh4kl&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) is a standard reference.

As a start, I recommend the short version of [Engel and Nagel](http://www.fa.uni-tuebingen.de/research/publications/2006/a-short-course-on-operator-semigroups/A_Short_Course_on_Operator_Semigroups.pdf), which is an excellent reading.

Answer (score 3):

I really like Brian Davies's "One parameter semigroups": it is short and well written. It does mostly focus on $C_0$-semigroups and not so much on analytic semigroups.

Then there's also the book by the old master, Yosida's "Functional analysis" which has a chapter on semigroup theory. His notations are a bit old-fashioned by now, but it's still an excellent reference book.

For an *extremely short* introduction to $C_0$ and analytic semigroups, see also Chapter 4 in my [SPDE lecture notes](http://www.hairer.org/notes/SPDEs.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that Pazy's is definitely a classic. In graduate school I recall reading parts of a very nice book by Aldo Belleni-Morante, "Applied Semigroups and Evolution Equations" (1979). The first part of this book contains numerous examples, detailed calculations, etc. (Just looking now, there is also "Applied Nonlinear Semigroups: An Introduction" by A. Belleni-Morante and A. C. McBride (1998).)